# How to find iframe in a dynamic id element in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I am trying to get the captcha button element with selenium in python. Although it use an iframe and a dynamic ID, token, class, etc. I have tried a few approaches but none of them worked.

The website has about 10 iframes, but 9 one them is "display: none" and one is "display: block", I am trying to access the 1 with display block. it randomize every time the site is reloaded.

My goal is to access this frame and then get the button element inside of the iframe by using something like `"[@style, 'display:block;']"`.

```html
            <iframe style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 100px; border: 0px; user-select: none;" token="844e3220622fa7bce9089559a53cf8e5f0f2c22840a629a45d9d6677fa2a3f44657458d20457f6af0552bb8a956fb355679ec7f58efd292e55620f6874f47058" title="Human verification challenge"></iframe>
        
        <iframe style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100px; border: 0; -moz-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none;" token="844e3220622fa7bce9089559a53cf8e5f0f2c22840a629a45d9d6677fa2a3f44657458d20457f6af0552bb8a956fb355679ec7f58efd292e55620f6874f47058" title="Human verification challenge"></iframe>
```

The code I am using now is:

```python
    try:
        total_frames = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')))
        print(total_frames)
        driver.switch_to.frame(total_frames[0])
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return 'Element does not exist'
```

But it returns an empty list `"[{}]"`. And I can't do anything.

I am fairly new to selenium although I have some programming background.

Answer (score 0):

```
elem=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@style,'display: block')]")
```

Simply find the iframe which has display block in it's style.

Comment: It did and didn't work. It found the element, although if i  try to switch to iframe it says "unable to find element", I tried using the find element as argument for the switch_to function